# Spock spy registers too few invocations (none) of Groovy method

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock

I have written a Groovy extension library that adds extra methods to the List class. I am trying to write tests for this using Spock but I am unable to get some of my tests to work.

**The code**

There are a number of methods that all have the same form. I have added methods that work the same as `tail()` (or `head()`, `first()`, etc.) but that will just return `null` if the List is empty, rather than throwing an Exception. An example is shown below (println()s added for troubleshooting):

```
public static def tailIfAny(List list) {

    println "tailIfAny() list.size(): ${list.size()}"

    def r = list.size() ? list.tail() : null
    println "r: $r"
    return r
}
```

I want to have two tests for `tailIfAny()`. The first test should check that no exception is thrown if you call the method on an empty List. This was straightforward and works. The other test I want to write is to check that `tail()` is called if the list is not empty.

**The test**

This is my test to check that `tail()` is called if the List is not empty:

```
def "tailIfAny() calls tail()"() {

    setup:
    def list = Spy(ArrayList)
    list << 'a'
    list << 'b'

    when:
    println "list ${list} -- ${list.size()}"
    println "Before tailIfAny()"
    list.tailIfAny()
    println "After tailIfAny()"

    then:
    1 * list.tail()
}
```

**The error message**

When I run me tests I get this failure message:

```
Too few invocations for:

1 * list.tail()   (0 invocations)

Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):

1 * list.toArray()
1 * list.iterator()
3 * list.size()
1 * list.isEmpty()


    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.InteractionScope.verifyInteractions(InteractionScope.java:78)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.MockController.leaveScope(MockController.java:76)
    at com.fgi.extensions.ListExtensionsTests.add element in setup(ListExtensionsTests.groovy:65)
```

But from the stdout output (below) I can see that `tail()` should have been called.

**The standard out from the tests**

```
list [a, b] -- 2
Before tailIfAny()
tailIfAny() list.size(): 2
r: [b]                      // This tells me that tail() is being called.
After tailIfAny()
```

**Can anyone shed some light on why Spock thinks that `tail()` isn't being called? or is there something going on here that I'm missing?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically, `tail()` isn't being called on the list object (`ArrayList` doesn't declare such a method). Therefore, the proxy-based `Spy()` doesn't get a chance to intercept the call. Try with `GroovySpy()`.

Comment: Groovy Mocks info: http://docs.spockframework.org/en/latest/interaction_based_testing.html#groovymocks